# SQL Server : create table columns for most efficient size

Tags: sql-server, database-design

My SQL Server database was created & designed by a freelance developer.

I see the database getting quite big and I want to ensure that the column datatypes are the most efficient in preserving the size as small as possible.

Most columns were created as

```
VARCHAR (255), NULL
```

This covers those where they are

- Numerics with a length of 2 numbers maximum
- Numerics where a length will never be more than 3 numbers or blank
- Alpha which will contain just 1 letter or are blank

Then there are a number of columns which are alphanumeric with a maximum of 10
alphanumeric characters with a maximum of 25.

There is one big alphanumeric column which can be up to 300 characters.

There has been an amendment for a column which show time taken in seconds to race an event. Under 1000 seconds and up to 2 decimal places

This is set as `DECIMAL (18,2) NULL`

The question is can I reduce the size of the database by changing the column data types, or was the original design, optimum for purpose?

Comment: Choose the data type most appropriate for the domain of data and storage will usually be most optimal. It seems decimal(6,2) is the right choice for the time taken, which will save 4 bytes compared to decimal(18,2).

Comment: Okay Dan that makes sense for this column. It was changed from the original VARCHAR(255) as it presented difficulties in using the data in that format. Big thanks for the comment....Chris

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned proper data types also facilitate data usability, such as comparison operators without type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely strive to use the **most appropriate** data types for all columns - and in this regard, that freelance developer did a very poor job - both from a point of **consistency** and **usability** (just try to sum up the numbers in a `VARCHAR(255)` column, or sort by their numeric value - horribly bad design...), but also from a performance point of view.

- *Numerics with a length of 2 numbers maximum*
- *Numerics where a length will never be more than 3 numbers or blank*

-> if you don't need any fractional decimal points (only whole numbers) - use `INT`

- *Alpha which will contain just 1 letter or are blank*

-> in this case, I'd use a `CHAR(1)` (or `NCHAR(1)` if you need to be able to handle Unicode characters, like Hebrew, Arabic, Cyrillic or east asian languages). Since it's really only ever 1 character (or nothing), there's no need or point in using a *variable-length* string datatype, since that only adds at least 2 bytes of overhead per string stored

- *There is one big alphanumeric column which can be up to 300 characters.*

-> That's a great candidate for a `VARCHAR(300)` column (or again: `NVARCHAR(300)` if you need to support Unicode). Here I'd definitely use a *variable-length* string type to avoid padding the column with spaces up to the defined length if you really want to store fewer characters.

Comment: The answer for this is as I suspected and I am grateful that this is clear now.   I will test the changes on some of the columns and hopefully when Shrinking the database will see the size reduce.       Chris ….

Comment: @no9chris - out of curiosity, how big is your database, both in terms of disk size and number of rows in these tables? Switching to the appropriate data types is definitely the way to go (even if disk space is not an issue), but I don't know how much disk space savings you'll see switching from `varchar(255)` to `int` unless you have gobs  of data.

Comment: I have carried out the column changes on a  copy of the main database which was only 127MB in size (5% of live one).  Having then run a SHRINK for this database I was surprised to see it GROW to 157MB.  Strange so I converted back the 12 columns to VARCHAR again. Did the Shrink & this time the result was 178MB total size. There is obviously a good reason behind this but it does not seem the objective of making the database more space efficient is not being achieved. Is this just an initial overhead?